# R Shiny - Getting the label of a radio button

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, label

I am trying to extract the label of the selected option in a radio button.
For example, I have a radio button called 'dist' and selected option is 'norm'

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
               c("Normal" = "norm",
                 "Uniform" = "unif",
                 "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
                 "Exponential" = "exp")),
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  x1 = input$dist
  print(x1) # gives 'norm' but I want 'Normal'
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I wanted to know the simplest method to implement this without using any outside construct like javascript etc.

Comment: Not sure if this is easy or even possible without JS. Can you explain why you think this is the solution for your underlying need? It might help if you clarify what the underlying need is, as perhaps there's another way to resolve the dilemma.

Comment: @r2evans So, I have a huge list of options and I have a uiOutput panel where I want to show which option is selected. So, I was thinking if there was a function to output the label of an input I'll use that to populate the output panel.

Comment: Since you're using `uiOutput`, that means you at some point *know* the label of the UI that has been added programmatically; in that case, you should be keeping track of your own labels instead of trying to determine dynamically what is present.

Comment: No I am not creating any control programatically. I have created then in UI section and just want to get the label of the radiobutton label on a text output.

Comment: (1) This isn't even a functional example of shiny, so it's really difficult to know what you mean, what works, and what is intended. (2) `uiOutput` is typically used with `renderUI` to dynamically add HTML controls (e.g., text entries, control sliders) at run-time based on user-entry or real-time events, or just to add "a lot of things" programmatically. It doesn't *need* to be used in that way, but that's why I jumped to that conclusion. Regardless, if you want to know the label, then create a named list of your radio button options and do a lookup. Reading `?radioButtons` might help some.

Comment: By that I mean: create a named list (vector) of radio labels/values, use that in your call to `radioButtons`, and then do a lookup based on `input$dist`. BTW: if you want anything to "react", you likely need some form of reactive blocks within your server component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the code provided does not work - the server code needs to be wrapped in `observe({ ... })` in order for it to function.

As for your question - there are two ways to approach this.

1. If the options are known ahead of time and are not dynamic, you can define the list of options as a separate variable that is accessible for both the UI and the server (if the ui and server are defined in separate files, then place it in a `global.R` file). Then simply look up the name based on the value.

   ```
    dist_options <- c("Normal" = "norm",
                      "Uniform" = "unif",
                      "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
                      "Exponential" = "exp")

    ui <- fluidPage(
      radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:", dist_options),
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {
      observe({
        x1 = input$dist
        print(names(which(dist_options == x1)))
      })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
   ```
2. If the options are dynamic, you will need to get involved with custom javascript code. Shiny will need to [ask javascript](https://deanattali.com/blog/advanced-shiny-tips/#message-r-to-javascript) for the label value of a specific input based on its value, and javascript will need to [communicate it back to shiny](https://deanattali.com/blog/advanced-shiny-tips/#message-javascript-r).

Comment: Oh, thanks! I think the first approach will work all right for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the label = NULL:

```
radioButtons("dist", label = NULL,
               c("Normal" = "norm",
                 "Uniform" = "unif",
                 "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
                 "Exponential" = "exp"))
```